# IE7 seems to be ignoring some css rules and failing to give some content height in an accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7

I'm developing a web page with a Google Maps element and a jquery UI accordion/tab based sidebar.  Everything is working pretty well in most modern browsers, but I've had several problems with IE7.  The web page is hosted here: http://jeffandkelly.net/map

There's a lot going on in the page; normally I'd try to create a jsfiddle, but I haven't been able to get that site working in IE7.  I've already employed numerous IE7-specific hacks, and now things are looking a lot better.  However, I've still got some issues.

My sidebar consists of a jquery UI accordion with 2 elements.  In the second element is a jquery UI tab control, and inside each tab are several `<div>` elements.  It's these elements that aren't behaving correctly in IE7 (shown left) vs Chrome (shown right).

[ie7 vs. chrome page rendering http://jeffandkelly.net/map/ie7-vs-chrome.jpg](http://jeffandkelly.net/map/ie7-vs-chrome.jpg)

First of all, I've got a CSS rule that should be hiding the headers for these elements (the "Safe Medicine Disposal Drop Off Location" text):

```
<h3 class="map-popup-header>Safe Medicine Disposal Drop Off Location</h3>
```

CSS:

```
.poi-holder .map-popup-header {
    display: none;
}
```

But IE7 doesn't apply that rule.  Second, IE7 hides the content that should be there (the F12 tools show that the elements are in the DOM, but have a height of 0).

Any help would be appreciated, as well as advice on some next steps to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there were multiple problems with the code.  First, IE7 requires tables to include `<tbody>` elements when creating content dynamically.  Therefore, the following code doesn't work without the commented line.

```
var infoTable = document.createElement('table');
var infoTbody = document.createElement('tbody'); //required for IE7!!
var infoTr = document.createElement('tr');
var infoTextTd = document.createElement('td');
var infoPhotoTd = document.createElement('td');
infoDiv.appendChild(infoTable);
infoTable.appendChild(infoTbody);
infoTbody.appendChild(infoTr);
infoTr.appendChild(infoTextTd);
infoTr.appendChild(infoPhotoTd);
```

Second, IE7 won't apply CSS rules to dynamically generated content given class attributes using `element.setAttribute('class', className)`.  It requires the use of `element.className = className`.

```
var header = document.createElement('h3');
header.className = 'map-popup-header'; //works as expected in IE7
var header = document.createElement('h3');
header.setAttribute('class','map-popup-header'); //doesn't work in IE7
```

Hope this answer can help someone else!